# Does Stack Overflow have a place to upload code that might be useful to the community?

Tags: discussion

I'm talking about more than 2k lines code, but if someone one day need something useful or a base model to get their own code started the code might be useful, wouldn't it??

If there is a place I would like to share my code!

Comment: I know you want to try and help, but if you ask a question specifically to share this code, it will be probably downvoted and most likely closed.  SO really isn't a place for sharing like this.  You can use your code to solve a problem (take Makoto's warning below seriously) in an answer, or later you can share it where appropriate in comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a GitHub Gist or repository and put the link in your profile.  Unless it *immediately* applies to the solution of a problem, **don't link to it in any of your answers**, and even then, be very aware that people may not want a link to a premade solution, and that not explaining *why* your premade solution  is ideal would easily result in downvotes.

Comment: Nice to know! Thank you, I'm not looking to do that, I was just asking if there was a place to put a code and explain what it does, the kind of formulas, methods, etc.  Any way, why people downvote questions??

Comment: I'd imagine that they might be downvoting the implied feature request of "Can we have a place to upload code that might be useful to the community?" Or they could think that your post is not useful, poorly research, or unclear. They might also have been the victim of tim losing his keys or any other random occurrence. That said, there are numerous posts about voting on meta, you should look for them.

Comment: @VVV: On meta, a question downvote means "I disagree with this proposal", or "I do not accept the premise of your question". People are saying "please don't do this", using downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

No, the model of SO is not to share random snippets of code, but to *answer* specific *questions* with detailed explanations, usually including code examples along with those explanations. Code by itself is just barely shy of deletion-worthy, since it doesn't explain things very well.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Stack Overflow have a place to upload code that might be useful to the community?

Yes, in certain limited contexts. You can ask a question detailing the problem solved by your code, and then self-answer with a brief explanation of how your code works and include the code within the body of the answer. Both of these things are critical components of a good answer. As Nathan Tuggy points out, a code dump alone is insufficient to constitute an answer.

Please don't link to an off-site resource containing the code, as those links have a tendency to decay over time, making your answer worthless.

Note that self-answered questions are held to the same standard as other questions on the site, so if this is to be workable, you need to figure out how to make the question on-topic, narrowly-focused, and useful to others. It also needs to be phrased as an actual question, not a blog post.

If you can't figure out how to make this work for the code you wish to share, then no—there is no "miscellaneous snippets" repository on Stack Overflow.

> I'm talking about more than 2k lines code

That is probably far too much. In fact, that sounds like an entire library. Libraries of code that you want to make public should be shared on a site like [GitHub](http://github.com/), [GitLab](http://gitlab.com/), [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.com/), or similar. Choose an appropriate license, and then do as Makoto suggested and add the link to your Stack Overflow profile to help promote it.

If this isn't a self-contained library, and you really do want to post it as a Q&A on Stack Overflow as described above, then you need to slim down the code to its bare essentials. Figure out which portions of it are actually relevant to solving a problem, and share only those. Strip out the boilerplate and miscellany.

> if someone one day need something useful or a base model to get their own code started the code might be useful

From this description, it sounds like what you have written may actually *just* be boilerplate. If that's the case, no—this kind of thing is not generally useful to the community and does not have a place where it can be shared. If you tried to ask a question so that you could self-answer, the question would be "too broad".

You *might* still be able to put this into a source repository, something akin to [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com), which isn't a library *per se*, but rather a template that people can use as a base model to help get them started. There might be answers where you could include this as a link (with a disclaimer that you are its author), but it would not itself constitute an answer to an on-topic question.